# XSLT 1.0 count and remove

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to check, if one “Item” has several nodes called "ItemDeliveryInformation" and if so, if the node "PackingSlipId" has the value "ohne Lieferschein".
e.g. one node "ItemDeliveryInformation"with “PackingSLipId = ohne Lieferschein” is ok, but if there are two ore more nodes "ItemDeliveryInformation" at “Item” it´s also ok, but if one of these several nodes has the value “ohne Lieferschein” at “PackingSlipId” the XSLT has to remove the whole node "ItemDeliveryInformation" where the “PackingSlipId = ohne Lieferschein”.

I started like that:

```html
<xsl:template match="Item[count(./ItemDeliveryInformation &lt; 1)] and Item/ItemDeliveryInformation[./PackingSlipId = 'ohne Lieferschein']">   
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Item[count(./ItemDeliveryInformation &lt; 1)] and Item/ItemDeliveryInformation[./PackingSlipId = 'ohne Lieferschein']"></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

wrong example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SALESINVOICE>
    <Interchange>
        <Test>No</Test>
    </Interchange>
    <HeaderInformation>
        <OrigInvoiceNumber>1</OrigInvoiceNumber>
    </HeaderInformation>
    <LineInformation>
        <Item>
            <LineNum>1000</LineNum>
            <GTIN>1234</GTIN>
            <ItemDeliveryInformation>
                <LineNumDeliveryNote>1000</LineNumDeliveryNote>
                <PackingSlipId_Created>2022-01-19T06:26:24</PackingSlipId_Created>
                <PackingSlipId>LS-0062820</PackingSlipId>
                <DeliveryDate>2022-01-19</DeliveryDate>
                <DeliveredQuantity>3.00</DeliveredQuantity>
                <ShipFromAddressInformation/>
            </ItemDeliveryInformation>
            <ItemDeliveryInformation>
                <LineNumDeliveryNote>1000</LineNumDeliveryNote>             
                <PackingSlipId>ohne Lieferschein</PackingSlipId>
                <DeliveryDate>2022-01-25</DeliveryDate>
                <DeliveredQuantity>3.00</DeliveredQuantity>
                <ShipFromAddressInformation/>
            </ItemDeliveryInformation>
                <ItemDeliveryInformation>
                <LineNumDeliveryNote>1000</LineNumDeliveryNote>
                <PackingSlipId_Created>2022-01-19T06:26:24</PackingSlipId_Created>
                <PackingSlipId>LS-0062822</PackingSlipId>
                <DeliveryDate>2022-01-19</DeliveryDate>
                <DeliveredQuantity>3.00</DeliveredQuantity>
                <ShipFromAddressInformation/>
            </ItemDeliveryInformation>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <LineNum>1002</LineNum>
            <GTIN>4657</GTIN>
            <ItemDeliveryInformation>
                <LineNumDeliveryNote>1002</LineNumDeliveryNote>
                <PackingSlipId_Created>2022-01-25</PackingSlipId_Created>
                <PackingSlipId>ohne Lieferschein</PackingSlipId>
                <DeliveryDate>2022-01-25</DeliveryDate>
                <DeliveredQuantity>1.00</DeliveredQuantity>
                <ShipFromAddressInformation/>
            </ItemDeliveryInformation>
        </Item>
    </LineInformation>
</SALESINVOICE>
```

correct example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SALESINVOICE>
   <Interchange>
      <Test>No</Test>
   </Interchange>
   <HeaderInformation>
      <OrigInvoiceNumber>1</OrigInvoiceNumber>
   </HeaderInformation>
   <LineInformation>
      <Item>
         <LineNum>1000</LineNum>
         <GTIN>1234</GTIN>
         <ItemDeliveryInformation>
            <LineNumDeliveryNote>1000</LineNumDeliveryNote>
            <PackingSlipId_Created>2022-01-19T06:26:24</PackingSlipId_Created>
            <PackingSlipId>LS-0062820</PackingSlipId>
            <DeliveryDate>2022-01-19</DeliveryDate>
            <DeliveredQuantity>3.00</DeliveredQuantity>
         </ItemDeliveryInformation>
         <ItemDeliveryInformation>
            <LineNumDeliveryNote>1000</LineNumDeliveryNote>
            <PackingSlipId_Created>2022-01-19T06:26:24</PackingSlipId_Created>
            <PackingSlipId>LS-0062822</PackingSlipId>
            <DeliveryDate>2022-01-19</DeliveryDate>
            <DeliveredQuantity>3.00</DeliveredQuantity>
         </ItemDeliveryInformation>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <LineNum>1002</LineNum>
         <GTIN>4657</GTIN>
         <ItemDeliveryInformation>
            <LineNumDeliveryNote>1002</LineNumDeliveryNote>
            <PackingSlipId_Created>2022-01-25</PackingSlipId_Created>
            <PackingSlipId>ohne Lieferschein</PackingSlipId>
            <DeliveryDate>2022-01-25</DeliveryDate>
            <DeliveredQuantity>1.00</DeliveredQuantity>
         </ItemDeliveryInformation>
      </Item>
   </LineInformation>
</SALESINVOICE>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item[…] and Item/ItemDeliveryInformation[…]` will never match because no node is both an `Item` and an `ItemDeliveryInformation`. Don't replicate the condition in match, that doesn't make sense.

You want to match on `ItemDeliveryInformation` and remove it if it both has the `ohne Lieferschein` and sibling nodes. Since *remove* is the absence of copying, invert the condition when copying:

```xml
<xsl:template match="Item/ItemDeliveryInformation">
  <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::ItemDeliveryInformation|following-sibling::ItemDeliveryInformation)=0 or PackingSlipId/text() != 'ohne Lieferschein'">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you have a generic copying template.

Comment: thanks, but in your output i got no node called "ItemDeliveryInformation"

I just want to remove the node "ItemDeliveryInformation" if the Item has more than one "ItemDeliveryInformation" and ALSO one of them has "ohne Lieferschein"

please see at: correct example, there you can see, i need the output of "ItemDeliveryInformation". Please let me if clear enough.

Comment: like that: <xsl:template match="Item/ItemDeliveryInformation[./PackingSlipId = 'ohne Lieferschein' and count(preceding-sibling::ItemDeliveryInformation|following-sibling::ItemDeliveryInformation)&gt; 1 and PackingSlipId/text() = 'ohne Lieferschein']"></xsl:template>

Comment: @juls_pro_37 sorry forgot the `<xsl:copy>`, should work now.

Comment: thanks a lot! now it looks good. thanks very much.